# TypeScript compile all ts files as a single JavaScript file in WebStorm 7

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I have a lot of .ts files in my project. WebStorm build each .ts file as a js file. But I dont want that.

I have an app.ts file and all other .ts files will be build in that app.ts file. How can I do that in WebStorm 7?

There is a solution in CLI mode but how can i implement it in WebStorm?

```
 tsc --out app.js main.ts app.ts a.ts b.ts
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

**ANSWER**

Just added this line at Arguments section in Edit Watcher

```
--sourcemap $FileName$ --out your-main.js
```

Comment: Why did you copy the answer into your question? That's not how this website works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify --out option in Typescript File watcher arguments, and, if 'track only root files' option is on, all ts files will be merged into a main js file (that imports them all directly or via references chain) on modifying any of them

Comment: 'track only root files' is checked but which file is the main js file? Can I choose main file in settings? Can you explain me with more specific information, Thanks.

Comment: the target file name (the one I called 'main js') is the one you use with --out option (app.js in your example). When you modify any of your ts files, the compiler will follow the references (///<reference path=’AnotherFile.ts’/>) chain and concatenate all the referenced files into a single JavaScript file with the specified name (app.js)

Comment: Thanks this is work for me. I'll edit my question with answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use grunt-ts which can maintain a `reference.ts` file for you, and point the webstorm file watcher to run your grunt task https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#javascript-generation-and-ordering

Disclaimer : I am one of the authors of grunt-ts.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't have a single file that links to all other ones and they don't want to maintain manually "references.ts" or using basarat's grunt-ts, here's my setup:

The basic idea is to list all your *.ts files into a text file and then use the file as a patameter for the tsc compiler. So I created my own file watcher and disabled the default one for TypeScript files. My file watcher's program is a bat file with following content:

```
dir /s /b /o:gn scripts\*.ts > ts_sources.txt
tsc %*
```

If you're on Mac or Linux you can easily transform this into a bash script.

On the watcher's setup screen you point to your batch file (bash script):

```
$ProjectFileDir$\compile.bat
```

and as your arguments you can have to use following:

```
@$ProjectFileDir$\ts_sources.txt --out $ProjectFileDir$\app_all.js --sourcemap
```

I guess there are many ways to do it...