# "track only root files" option on Type Script Edit Watcher Page

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I want to do what the following questioner wanted to do, namely create a single js file out of multiple ts files.

[TypeScript compile all ts files as a single JavaScript file in WebStorm 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816695/typescript-compile-all-ts-files-as-a-single-javascript-file-in-webstorm-7)

I am using Version 10.0.4 of WebStorm 10, under the month long free trial. I don't have the "track only root files" option on my Type Script Edit Watcher page. Shouldn't I?

Comment: Really recommend not using `out` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Answer (score 0):

It's called `'Compile main files only'`in WebStorm 10