# TypeScript compiler creates empty JavaScript file in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

It is my initial experience with TypeScript. I took a simple JavaScript app consisting of two files and converted them to TypeScript.

One file `accounts.ts` contains the main code, the other one `fiat.ts` is a support file which exports a module `Fiat` with some exported members. After some editing I got no more error messages from the TypeScript compiler.

I use a `tsconfig.json` file to control the compilation:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outFile": "main.js",
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "accounts.ts",
    "fiat.ts"
  ]
}
```

It should create a `main.js` file containing the code. But this contains after a successful compilation only one line:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

No other code gets included. I found by accident that if I remove the line

```
import {Fiat} from './fiat';
```

in the `accounts.ts` file then the compiler includes the code of `accounts.ts` into `main.js` but not the code of `fiat.ts` and additionally the TypeScript compiler shows error messages for each reference to `Fiat` in `accounts.ts`.

I cannot figure out how to create a JavaScript file from just two TypeScript files. Any help would be appreciated!

---

What I found after some research: The Typescript module concept can be handeled in two different ways: internal and external modules. My difficulties came from not really understanding this. External modules work with a dynamic module loader. You `import` them. Only internal modules can be lumped together into one (or multiple) Javascript file(s) that get loaded with the HTML via the `script` tag. To work with internal modules you need `/// <reference path="./name.ts" />` lines in the files that reference them. Other syntax differences between internal and external modules are minor as far as I know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript compile all ts files as a single JavaScript file in WebStorm 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816695/typescript-compile-all-ts-files-as-a-single-javascript-file-in-webstorm-7)

Comment: I saw that and tried to understand it. The guy there used file watchers, I use the compiler directly. Might not be such a difference but the compiler options proposed there did nothing for my problem. It seems to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use modules (external modules) and compile them in single file you should set `module` to target `amd` or `system` (assuming you have [1.8 typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile)) in your tsconfig.json.

By removing import/export you do not use modules and thus `outFile` works.

Comment: Yes I saw that somewhere explained and tried this as well. It leads to Javascript code which does not execute. With the 'amd' option I get a "define is not defined" and with "system" a "System is not defined" error in the browser console.

Comment: What loader are you using?

Comment: Remember browsers does not yet have ability to load modules - you need to use one like systemjs, requirejs, etc

Comment: What confuses me is the fact that I first created the 'fiat.ts' with the module in it and used it from within a Javascript version of 'accounts.js'. This worked like a charm. I did not need a module loader, I just included the generated 'fiat.js' in the web page and it was usable. Why doesn't this work with one more Typescript file which not even contains a module but is just the updated Javascript version? This is weiered. With the second Typescript file the transpiler started to generate different code.

Comment: It does not work due to how tsc is bild. tsc will not emit code if target is commonjs and you are using multiple files together with outFile option. In general modules are not meant to be used with one file only.

Comment: I have removed the module declaration. It does not change anything. I'm not married to the "one output file" solution. I'm just looking for a way to use two different Typescript files without the need for a dynamic module loader. Can someone tell me if that is generally impossible?

Comment: If you do not want to use modules and loaders - then use namespaces: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: It is not a question of modules or namespaces but ruther one of internal / external modules. I have added the answer to my question above.

Comment: FYI. internal modules were renamed to namespaces. So now there are modules or namespaces. this was done to reduce confusion.